# Django webpage only displays properly if a character is placed after {% load static %}

Tags: django

If I structure the first two lines of my HTML doc like this:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

It appears that none of the javascript or CSS run properly, and the webpage displays like this:

[image]

However, if I put any character after the `{% load static %}` expression,
For example, if I structure the first two lines of my HTML doc like this:

```
{% load static %}.
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Then the scripts and CSS components run properly and the webpage displays as it should. Why is this?

Comment: maybe because then the html doc isn't empty anymore

Comment: @Sven I'm trying to find a workaround to not have to put the '.' in, as its messing up facebook's share debugger from reading the <head> tags correctly.

Comment: Well for loading css you have to put something like ```<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">``` in the <head>

Comment: Yes, I've done that, and the CSS loads fine as long as I put the '.' after {% load static %}, as stated in the question. The issue is that it doesn't work if I remove the '.'  after {% load static %}, and I'm trying to figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. For some reason, the content security policy that I had implemented was causing this issue. After removing the CSP, the static files began to behave in-line with expectations regardless of the presence/absence of a character after `{% load static %}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

You did it right but you have load the static files too like i did below.

```
<!-- js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- js -->
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-select.js' %}"></script>
```

You have to use this tag to load static files in template "{% static %}" this is the syntax for load static files.

```
#And give it the path in settings.py 

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    ]
```

And store css and js in static folder in your project too.Than its gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the STATIC_URL of your settings is correct.

Comment: The STATIC_URL is definitely correct because all static files load correctly as long as there is a '.' after {% load static %}. The issue is that it stops loading if I remove the '.', and I can't figure out why